# Manipulate massive array of strings

Tags: php, arrays, string, command-line-interface

From one of our vendors I received a DVD with 12K+ images. Before i put them on our webserver, I need to resize, rename and copy them.
To do this I'm writing a PHP cli program.
And it seems that I am a little stuck with it...

All the files fit a certain pattern.

The copy and rename are not the problem, the manipulation of the strings is.

So to symplify the example code: lets suppose that I have an array with strings and I want to put them into a new array.

The original array looks like this:

```
$names = array (
 'FIX1_VARA_000.1111_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARB_000.1111.2_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARB_222.2582_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARC_555.8794_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARD_111.0X00(2-5)_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARA_112.01XX(09-13)_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARB_444.XXX1(203-207).2_FIX2'    
);
```

Each string in this array starts with the same fixed part in the front and ends with the same fixed part in the end FIX1 & FIX2 respectively.
After FIX1 there always is an underscore followed by a variable part, followed by an underscore. I'm not interested in the fixed parts or the variable parts. So I cut it all away.

The remaining string can be of the following two types:
If it only contains numbers and points: then it is a valid string and I put it 
in the $clean array. EG: 000.1111  or 000.111.2
If the string does not only have numbers and points in it, then it always has several X's in it and a an open an closed bracked with numbers and a -.
Like 444.XXX1(203-207).2

The numbers between the brackets form a series, and each number in this series needs to replace the X's. The strings that should be put in the $clean array are:

444.2031.2

444.2041.2

444.2051.2

444.2061.2

444.2071.2

This is the part I'm struggling with.

```
$clean = array();
foreach ($names as $name){
    $item = trim(strstr(str_replace(array('FIX1_', '_FIX2'),'',$name), '_'),'_');
    // $item get the values:
    /*  
     * 000.1111, 
     * 000.1111.2, 
     * 222.2582, 
     * 555.8794, 
     * 111.0X00(2-5), 
     * 112.01XX(09-13), 
     * 444.XXX1(203-207).2 
     *  
     */

    // IF an item has no X in it, it can be put in the $clean array
    if (strpos($item,'X') === false){
        //this is true for the first 4 array values in the example
        $clean[] = $item;
    }
    else {
        //this is for the last 3 array values in the example
        $b = strpos($item,'(');
        $e = strpos($item,')');
        $sequence = substr($item,$b,$e-$b+1);

        $item = str_replace($sequence,'',$item);

        /* This is the part were I'm stuck */
        /* ------------------------------- */
        /* it should get the values in the sequence variable and iterate over them:
         * 
         * So for $names[5] ('FIX1_VARA_112.01XX(09-13)_FIX2') I want the folowing values entered into the $clean array:
         * Value of $sequence = '(09-13)'
         * 
         * 112.0109
         * 112.0110
         * 112.0111
         * 112.0112
         * 112.0113
         *  
         */      
    }
}

//NOW ECHO ALL VALUES IN $clean:
foreach ($clean as $c){
    echo $c . "\n";
}
```

The final output should be:

```
000.1111
000.1111.2
222.2582
555.8794
111.0200
111.0300
111.0400
111.0500
112.0109
112.0110
112.0111
112.0112
112.0113
444.2031.2
444.2041.2
444.2051.2
444.2061.2
444.2071.2
```

Any help with the "Here I'm stuck" part would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 12k is not massive. BTW there are hundreds of ready to use classes out there ...

Comment: be careful with `strpos($item,'X') == false`, you should use `===`, otherwise, the position `0` will be considered as `false` since `0 == false`

Comment: You can just split the strings into array using `_` as delimiter and take the third part

Comment: Is there are reason you are not just using `glob` http://php.net/glob to scan the folders?

Comment: @Random: valid point, I changed the == into ===

Comment: @Cmorrissey: The full program uses glob to scan the folder. But that part I already figured out. So I just simplified to code to get to the string manipulation part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @stdob-- mentioned, regular expressions really are what you want. Here's a working version of the code:

```
$names = array (
 'FIX1_VARA_000.1111_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARB_000.1111.2_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARB_222.2582_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARC_555.8794_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARD_111.0X00(2-5)_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARA_112.01XX(09-13)_FIX2',
 'FIX1_VARB_444.XXX1(203-207).2_FIX2'
);

$clean = array();
foreach ($names as $name){
    $item = trim(strstr(str_replace(array('FIX1_', '_FIX2'),'',$name), '_'),'_');
    // $item get the values:
    /*
     * 000.1111,
     * 000.1111.2,
     * 222.2582,
     * 555.8794,
     * 111.0X00(2-5),
     * 112.01XX(09-13),
     * 444.XXX1(203-207).2
     *
     */

    // IF an item has no X in it, it can be put in the $clean array
    if (strpos($item,'X') === false){
        //this is true for the first 4 array values in the example
        $clean[] = $item;
    }
    else {
        // Initialize the empty matches array (I prefer [] to array(), but pick your poison)
        $matches = [];

        // Check out: https://www.regex101.com/r/qG4jS4/1 to see visually how this works (also, regex101.com is just rad)
        // This uses capture groups, which get stored in the $matches array.
        preg_match('/\((\d*)-(\d*)\)/', $item, $matches);

        // Now we've got the array of values that we want to have in our clean array
        $range = range($matches[1], $matches[2]);

        // Since preg_match has our parenthesis and digits grabbed for us, get rid of those from the string
        $item = str_replace($matches[0],'',$item);


        // Truly regrettable variable names, but you get the idea!
        foreach($range as $number){
            // Here's where it gets ugly. You're wanting the numbers to work like strings (have consistent length
            // like 09 and 13) but also work like numbers (when you create a sequence of numbers). That kind of
            // thinking begets hackery. This probably isn't your fault, but it seems helpful to point out.

            // Anyways, we can use the number of X's in the string to figure out how many characters we ought
            // to be adding. This is important because otherwise we'll end up with 112.019 instead of 112.0109.
            // PHP casts that '09' to (int) 9 when we run the range() function, so we lose the leading zero.
            $xCount = substr_count($item, 'X');

            if($xCount > strlen($number)){
                // This function adds a given number ($xCount, in our case) of a character ('0') to
                // the end of a string (unless it's given the STR_PAD_LEFT flag, in which case it adds
                // the padding to the left side)
                $number = str_pad($number, $xCount, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            }

            // With a quick cheat by padding an empty string with the same number of X's we counted earlier...
            $xString = str_pad('', $xCount, 'X');

            // Now we can add the fixed string into the clean array.
            $clean[] = str_replace($xString, $number, $item);
        }
    }
}

// I also happen to prefer var_dump to echo, but again, your mileage may vary.
var_dump($clean);
```

It outputs:

```
array (size=18)
  0 => string '000.1111' (length=8)
  1 => string '000.1111.2' (length=10)
  2 => string '222.2582' (length=8)
  3 => string '555.8794' (length=8)
  4 => string '111.0200' (length=8)
  5 => string '111.0300' (length=8)
  6 => string '111.0400' (length=8)
  7 => string '111.0500' (length=8)
  8 => string '112.0109' (length=8)
  9 => string '112.0110' (length=8)
  10 => string '112.0111' (length=8)
  11 => string '112.0112' (length=8)
  12 => string '112.0113' (length=8)
  13 => string '444.2031.2' (length=10)
  14 => string '444.2041.2' (length=10)
  15 => string '444.2051.2' (length=10)
  16 => string '444.2061.2' (length=10)
  17 => string '444.2071.2' (length=10)
```

--Edit-- Removed my warning about `strpos` and `==`, looks like somebody already pointed that out in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll suppose all your files have valid patterns, so no file has something wrong in it, otherwise, just add security conditions...
in `$sequence`, you get the `(09-13)`.
To use digits, you have to remove `(` and `)`, so make an other variable :

```
$range = substr($item,$b,$e-$b+1);
// you get '09-13'
```

then you need to split it :

```
list($min, $max) = explode("-",$range);
// $min = '09', $max = '13'
$nbDigits = strlen($max);
// $nbDigits = 2
```

Then you need all digits from min to max :

```
$numbersList = array();
$min = (int)$min; // $min becomes 9, instead of '09'
$max = (int)$max;
for($i=(int)$min; $i<=(int)$max; $i++) {
    // set a number, including leading zeros
    $numbersList[] = str_pad($i, $nbDigits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Then you have to generate file names with those digits :

```
$xPlace = strpos($item,'X');
foreach($numbersList as $number) {
    $filename = $item;
    for($i=0; $i<$nbDigits; $i++) {
        // replacing one digit at a time, to replace each 'X'
        $filename[$xPlace+$i] = $number[$i];
    }
    $clean[] = $filename;
}
```

It should do some work, there may be some errors, but it is a good start, give it a try :)